# Android Studio Gradle Dependencies not resolving

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hi guys trying to add the following gradle dependency in an android studio project:

```
compile "io.swagger:openalpr_api:2.0.1"
```

Sync keeps failing saying that it is unable to resolve, have made sure global settings are not on offline and tried changing standard repositories to mavenCentral but still receiving the same failed to resolve error.

Can someone try to import the above dependency to check if its not just me?

Thanks for any help or advice

Comment: A Google search on `"io.swagger" "openalpr_api"` suggests that there may be no artifact by the name `io.swagger:openalpr_api`. Where did you get that artifact name from?

Comment: I'm following the installation instructions from the github repo:
https://github.com/openalpr/cloudapi/tree/master/java

Answer (score 0):

That artifact does not appear to be hosted online. Instead, [the documentation instructs you](https://github.com/openalpr/cloudapi/tree/master/java#installation) to execute a local Maven build, deploying the artifact to a local Maven repository.